# Generating random string based on some hex

Tags: python, string, random, passwords, md5

I have a md5 checksum in python; like `s = '14966ba801aed57c2771c7487c7b194a'`.

What I want is to shorten it and make it a string in the form 'a-zA-Z0-9_.-', without loosing entropy of my random md5 checksum.

The output have to be pronounceable, so I cant just do `binascii.unhexlify(s)`. Nor can I do `base64.encodestring(s)` and cut it because then I will loose entropy.

Any ideas on how to solve this without mapping an insane number (256) of hex pair (00->FF) to different letters?

The reason I want this is to be able to say a whole md5 checksum over the phone, but use the whole alphabet+numbers+some special characters.

Comment: Maybe `hash(s)` or `hex(hash(s))`?

Comment: Well, hex is basically a way of encoding to base 16; encoding to base 65 (26+26+10+3) shouldn't be all that different (except there's no built-in function to do it).

Comment: What use case did require you to want this?

Comment: Assuming a random `s`, you want to *shorten* it without lowering the entropy? I hope you realize this is non-sensical

Comment: I want the md5 checksum to be shorter. A human is supposed to say it over the phone, and therefor it is better to shorten it and use the whole alphabet+numbers. I can also use uppercase and lowercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want the "number" (yes, a md5 hash is nothing but a base16 number, we can of course convert that to base-something to shorten the string) to be pronouncable over the phone, I suggest avoiding mixed upper- / lowercase.
And when we only allow [0-9A-Z], we can simply use the builtin int() with Base36 for decoding.

See:

```
>>> def encode(num):
        import string
        ALPHABET = string.digits + string.ascii_uppercase
        tmp = []
        while num:
            num, rem = divmod(num, len(ALPHABET))
            tmp.append(ALPHABET[rem])
        return ''.join(reversed(tmp))

>>> import hashlib
>>> the_hash = hashlib.md5('test').hexdigest()
>>> decimal_representation = int(the_hash, 16)
>>> encoded = encode(decimal_representation)
>>> the_hash
'098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6'
>>> decimal_representation
12707736894140473154801792860916528374L
>>> encoded
'KDISMNX5MOYU6Q6PZT8TQDPY'
>>> decimal_representation == int(encoded, 36)
True
>>> hex(int(encoded, 36))
'0x98f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6L'
```

You could of course use a longer alphabet to shorten the resulting string, but then you'd have to write your own decode() function. Should not be too hard, though.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted.. I changed it to take string.ascii_letters + '1234567890' + ',.-_*!|@#$%&=+?' as characters and it works just as you would expect. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to play fast and loose with your requirements a little and take a shot at something which I think might help you.

Reading over what you've written, the requirement that stands out to me is a way to read a message digest over the phone.

To that end, you might want to look at [Bubble Babble](http://wiki.yak.net/589).  Bubble Babble is designed to encode a digest (or other things) into a pronounceable string:

```
ASCII Input       Encoding
------------------------------------------------------------------
`' (empty string) `xexax'
`1234567890'      `xesef-disof-gytuf-katof-movif-baxux'
`Pineapple'       `xigak-nyryk-humil-bosek-sonax'
```

Here's a Python implementation: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/299133-bubblebabble/

Comment: +1, I was going to suggest this after I saw that the use case was that some one had to read the string to another person over a telephone.

Comment: Good tip, and I think I can use this. However, the ultimate solution for me would be to bring the length down and use a-zA-Z0-9..

Answer (score 0):

- short answer: you can't
- longr answer:
  a md5 hashsum contains 128 bits of information, so to store that you also need 128 bits. the closest you get from that to a human readable form would probably be to base64 encode it, that will leave you with 22 characters (24 with padding). that's probably as short as it gets.*

  where does the randomness in your md5 hash come from anyway? md5 hashes arn't random, so you're probably hashing something random (what?) to get them (and by doing so you can't increase the entropy in any way, only decrease it).

*you could probably create you own way to encode the checksum using a larger range of characters from the unicode range... but that would mean you had to select a suitable set of characters that anybody will know how to pronounce...
something like `☺ ⚓ ⚔ ☂ ☏` would seem fairly clear, but some symbols like `♨` no so much...

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The md5 sum is calculated, so its not "random" it that sense. The md5 sum is also 32 character long, so getting it down to 22 is much better. With extended printable ascii I can get it down to around 17-18 (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength#Random_passwords).

Comment: i get it that you're using the hex-digest, which is already an encoded representation. it's better to use the raw digest in this case - something like: `hashlib.new("md5", "test").digest().encode('base64')`